# What are the open problems in the field of quantum thermodynamics?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, open-quantum-systems

I came across the Lindblad equation and found it very interesting. **What are the open problems in the field of [quantum thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_thermodynamics)?**

Comment: This question (v2) seems like a list question.

Answer (score 5):

This is an active field of research with very many open problems, a summary of which would constitute a partially subjective list and thus be inappropriate for this site. You might find the following review useful, which provides a nice survey of the current status of the field and extensive references: [Goold et al., J. Phys. A: Math. Theor. 49 143001 (2016).](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.07835)